# How to use instantiated variable from included PHP file?

Tags: php, variables, include, instantiation

I have a .php file that is included in another one. and the included one has a class definition, and an object instantiation

included.php:

```
class MyClass
{
//works
}

$anObject = new MyClass();
```

includer.php:

```
require_once("./included.php");
echo $anObject->localVariable;
```

returns error : undefined variable: anObject in includer.php

how can I do this? or can I do this?

Comment: Is that the exact warning that is returned?

Comment: Seems to work on my local machine here...

Comment: @jeroen yes, except file and variable names.

Comment: Can you post the complete error message / warning?

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: bir in C:\xampp\htdocs\projecteuler\index.php on line 9

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\projecteuler\index.php on line 9

Comment: it would be better coding practice for the included file to contain just the class definition and no other code, and to instantiate the object separately in the main program.

Comment: Of course, but I want some constants because I include that file in many other files and I don't want to declare the same constant over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make you $anObject variable as a global.

```
global $anObject;
$anObject = new MyClass();
```

Comment: I tried it, now the error is: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: @marvin, you have a syntax error. You can show me a line where this error.

Comment: global $bir = new bigint("1");

Comment: `global $var;` has to be on a line of its own, you can't set a value at the same time.